# Ассемблерная вставка в Си

Tags: c, ассемблер

Пытаюсь разобраться, как вставить код на ассемблере в Си код. Беглый поиск по гугл лишь запутал. Попытка что-то скомпилировать из написанного не увенчалась успехом. Может ли кто-нибудь мне привести два варианта рабочего кода, для linux/windows (x64), который бы выражал следующие идеи:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c;

    __assembly__ {
        mov    eax, a
        mov    ebx, b
        add    eax, ebx
        mov    c, eax
    }

    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

п.с. Я правильно понимаю, что для этих целей нужно использовать GAS? Нет никакой возможности заставить компилятор понимать вставки на NASM?

Comment: Для этих целей нужно использовать ГОЛОВУ и кучу разной документации, начиная от понимания что такое CPU architectural ABI и как его готовить.

Comment: @0andriy хм, дерзко. А вот Крис Касперски так не считал, когда советовал новичкам (в своих статьях) изучать ассемблер с привязкой к Си, ибо так куда проще и понятней. Там же и привёл рабочий код подобной программы, но видать рабочий для того времени. Наверно он просто баран... да? п.с. что-то мне подсказывает, что мне если покажут правильный синтаксис, то этот код магическим образом заработает. Без кучи разной докуметации, CPU, ABI, и их приготовления. И да, без головы тоже. Догадка.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2014/04/18/lets-write-some-x86-64/

Comment: И так далее... Не знаю, кто такой этот Крис, для меня источником информации может служить документация, написанный и рабочий код (с указанием версий компилятора и других важных моментов), и тому подобное.

Comment: @0andriy спасибо за ссылки, ознакомлюсь.

Comment: Не знаю, почему заминусовали, вопрос-то неплохой.

Comment: @0andriy, причем здесь calling conventions, если автор просто складывает переменные?

Comment: Для GNU читайте [тут](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) (также обратите внимание на раздел **Multiple assembler dialects in asm templates**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, более правильный путь использования ассемблера в Си, не вставками и смешиванием Си и ассемблера, а линковкой скомпилированного ассемблера.

Т.е. пишите на любимом NASM (к примеру) в файл `test.asm`:

```
section .text

global _add

_add:
    mov rax, rcx
    add rax, rdx
ret
```

компилируете:

```
nasm -f win64 test.asm -o test.o
```

Далее, вызываете эту функцию из Си:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int _add(int, int);

int main()
{
    int i = _add(5, 10);
    printf("i = %d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

При сборке не забывайте указать линковщику, чтобы он линковался с `test.o`:

```
gcc -Wall -g  -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -o asm_test.exe main.o test.o
```

---

Чтобы собрать тоже самое под Linux, вам нужно будет привести ассемблерный код в соответствие с соглашением о передаче параметров в Unix 64-bit (отличается от соглашения для Win64) и указать NASM другой выходной формат:

```
nasm -f elf64 test.asm -o test.o
```

О соглашениях передачи параметров и об особенностях написания 64-битного кода, в NASM посвящена отдельная глава в документации: [Writing 64-bit Code (Unix, Win64)](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.03/html/nasmdo11.html)

Comment: спасибо, всё работает. Вот только вопрос, что должна делать эта программа? Если она производит операцию сложения двух переданных в функцию чисел и возвращает результат (догадка), то на выходе я получаю i = -73838672 итп. При каждом запуске разное значение. У вас всё окей?

Comment: @NotSure Чтобы сделать ассемблерный код кроссплатформенным, всё-таки придётся немного больше потрудиться. [Соглашения о передаче параметров в Win64 и Unix64 не совпадают](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.03/html/nasmdo11.html#section-11.3) и в Linux входные параметры попадут в `rdi`, `rsi`, а не в `rcx` и `rdx`.

Comment: а также чтобы сделать его кроссплатформенным в данном ключе (и даже переносимым в рамках всего x86 семейства) можно воспользоваться ассемблерными вставками =))

Comment: @Fat-Zer Можно конечно, но смысл использования именно ассемблера в таком случае, по-моему, теряется. Уж лучше тогда на обычном Си написать. И да, [в серьёзных проектах](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/tree/master/simd), где ассемблер используется не баловства ради, под каждую платформу пишется своя реализация, с учётом всех возможных оптимизаций в каждом конкретном случае.

Comment: @zed, мм... для меня ассемблер это скорее способ работать со спец. регистрами и, иногда, спец. командами, в случае если в компилятор/libc забыли встроить встроить готовые инструменты для этого... и в этом отношении ассемблерные вставки gcc довольно гибкие, а при аккуратном обращении позволяют свести затраты на вызовы практически до нуля... не спорю, что целые алгоритмы обёрнутые в функции будет удобней писать отдельно.

Answer (score 5):

Начинается оператор ассемблерной вставки с ключевого слова [`asm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm) или `__asm__`, после чего в **круглых** скобках следует ее описание.

Синтаксис оператора следующий:

```
asm (
     текст_вставки :
     список_выходных_параметров :
     список_входных_параметров :
     список_разрушаемых_регистров
)
```

**Текст вставки** представляет собой строковую константу с ассемблерными инструкциями. В нем могут находиться не только ассемблерные инструкции, но и любые директивы [ассемблера GAS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler).

> Для связи ассемблерных инструкций и переменных внешнего C-кода
>   используются два элемента оператора: списки операндов, в которых
>   операнды перечислены через запятую.  Каждый описанный операнд затем
>   может использоваться в ассемблерных инструкциях, обращение к нему
>   осуществляется по номеру с префиксом `%`. Нумерация начинается с 0, и
>   идет непрерывно, объединяя все элементы списков выходных и входных
>   операндов.

Операнд имеет следующий вид:

```
ограничение_типа (имя_переменной)
```

`имя_переменной` — ни что иное, как имя C-переменой, значение которой вы хотите использовать в ассемблерном коде.

`ограничение_типа` — строковая константа, описывает допустимый тип операнда.

Для *выходных* операндов строка ограничения типа должна начинаться с символа `=`.

---

Итак, этого достаточно, чтобы написать ваш пример:

```
int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c;

    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t" // директива GAS, включаем Intel синтаксис.
        "mov eax, %1\n\t"            // перемещаем в eax значение переменной a.
        "add eax, %2\n\t"            // прибавляем значение переменной b к eax.
        "mov %0, eax\n\t"            // перемещаем в переменную c значение eax.
        :"=r"(c)                     // список выходных параметров.
        :"r"(a), "r"(b)              // список входных параметров.
        : "eax"                      // список разрушаемых регистров.
    );

    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

---

В общем-то писал по [этому](http://asmcourse.cs.msu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/gcc-inline-asm.pdf) документу. Неплохая информация представлена [здесь](http://av-assembler.ru/asm/high-level-languages/assembler-gcc.php).

Comment: Вот откуда уверенность, что *%r0* не задействован внутри функции? (Вопрос риторический для меня)

Comment: Наверное, надо добавить в список разрушаемых регистров `eax`, ну и замечание не помешает вставить: *Важно  помнить,  что  ассемблерная  вставка  негативно  сказывается  на производительности программы. Связывание операндов  вставки и переменных Си-программы требует дополнительных  инструкций  копирования,  но,  самое  главное,  вставки  меняют  области применения  оптимизирующих  преобразований  кода,  не  позволяя  им  достичь  должных результатов.*

Comment: @zed, список разрушаемых регистров добавил. А на счет замечания… думаю, нет смысла перепечатывать мануалы, автору ведь просто пример рабочей программы нужен.

Comment: @0andriy, что за `%r0`?

Comment: Регистр. Zed, например, понял, что я говорю, а вы нет. Вот и отличный пример «обучения по-Касперски».

Comment: @0andriy, ну, если вы обучены не «по-Касперски» могли бы и сами написать ответ. Автор попросил рабочий пример — я прочитал мануалы, написал пример и оформил ответ. Конечно, если *кто-нибудь* напишет ответ лучше, свой я удалю.

Comment: @eanmos спасибо за ответ и за ссылки. ознакомлюсь с материалом. пример правда у меня не "завёлся" ни на винде, ни на линкусе. ругается на синтаксис почему-то.

Comment: @NotSure, был рад помочь :) Попробуйте скомпилировать с флагом `-masm=intel`.

Comment: Ответ @zed лучше по моему мнению. Ваш ход?

Comment: @0andriy, ну, во-первых это по вашему мнению — голоса распределились иначе. А во вторых, его ответ ни лучше, ни хуже, он *совершенно* другой, если вы не заметили. У меня про ассемблерные вставки, у него — про линковку.

Comment: Ваш код не запускается. Для того, чтобы он запускался и работал надо последней командой добавить ".att_syntax prefix".