# всёравно файл не компилиться там какие-то ошибки port.cpp

Tags: c++, c

сначала выкладываю сообщение об ошибках:

```
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS5$ make run
g++ -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -o port.o -c port.cpp
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint8_t Port8Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:41:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In constructor ‘Port8BitSlow::Port8BitSlow(uint16_t)’:
port.cpp:48:3: error: type ‘Port’ is not a direct base of ‘Port8BitSlow’
 : Port(portnumber)
   ^
port.cpp:48:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘Port8Bit::Port8Bit()’
 : Port(portnumber)
                  ^
port.cpp:16:1: note: candidate: Port8Bit::Port8Bit(uint16_t)
 Port8Bit::Port8Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
 ^
port.cpp:16:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from port.cpp:2:0:
port.h:17:11: note: candidate: Port8Bit::Port8Bit(const Port8Bit&)
     class Port8Bit : public Port
           ^
port.h:17:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:94:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint32_t Port32Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:128:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint8_t Port8Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:41:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:94:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint32_t Port32Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:128:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
Makefile:9: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «port.o»
make: *** [port.o] Ошибка 1
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS5$ make clean
rm -f loader.o gdt.o port.o kernel.o mykernel.bin mykernel.iso
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS5$ make run
as --32 -o loader.o loader.s
g++ -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -o gdt.o -c gdt.cpp
g++ -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -o port.o -c port.cpp
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint8_t Port8Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:41:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In constructor ‘Port8BitSlow::Port8BitSlow(uint16_t)’:
port.cpp:48:3: error: type ‘Port’ is not a direct base of ‘Port8BitSlow’
 : Port(portnumber)
   ^
port.cpp:48:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘Port8Bit::Port8Bit()’
 : Port(portnumber)
                  ^
port.cpp:16:1: note: candidate: Port8Bit::Port8Bit(uint16_t)
 Port8Bit::Port8Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
 ^
port.cpp:16:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from port.cpp:2:0:
port.h:17:11: note: candidate: Port8Bit::Port8Bit(const Port8Bit&)
     class Port8Bit : public Port
           ^
port.h:17:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:94:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint32_t Port32Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:128:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint8_t Port8Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:41:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:94:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
port.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint32_t Port32Bit::Read()’:
port.cpp:128:6: error: input operand constraint contains ‘=’
     );
      ^
Makefile:9: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «port.o»
make: *** [port.o] Ошибка 1
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS5$
```

Теперь сам код исправленный спасибо @Zed

```
#include "port.h"

Port::Port(uint16_t portnumber)
{
    this->portnumber = portnumber;
}

Port::~Port()
{
}




Port8Bit::Port8Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber) 
{
}

Port8Bit::~Port8Bit()
{
}

void Port8Bit::Write(uint8_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile (
        "outb %0, %1" 
        :
        : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber)
    );
}

uint8_t Port8Bit::Read()
{
    uint8_t result;
    __asm__ volatile (
        "inb %1, %0"
        :
        : "=a" (result), "Nd" (portnumber)
    );
    return result;
}



Port8BitSlow::Port8BitSlow(uint16_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port8BitSlow::~Port8BitSlow()
{
}

void Port8BitSlow::Write(uint8_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile (
        "outb %0, %1\njmp 1f\n1: jmp 1f\n1:"
        :
        : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber)
    );
}





Port16Bit::Port16Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port16Bit::~Port16Bit()
{
}

void Port16Bit::Write(uint16_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile (
        "outw %0, %1" 
        :
        : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber)
    );
}

uint16_t Port16Bit::Read()
{
    uint16_t result;
    __asm__ volatile (
        "inw %1, %0" 
        :
        : "=a" (result), "Nd" (portnumber)
    );
    return result;
}






Port32Bit::Port32Bit(uint16_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port32Bit::~Port32Bit()
{
}

void Port32Bit::Write(uint32_t data)
{
    __asm__ volatile (
        "outl %0, %1" 
        :
        : "a" (data), "Nd" (portnumber)
    );
}

uint32_t Port32Bit::Read()
{
    uint32_t result;
    __asm__ volatile (
        "inl %1, %0" 
        :
        : "=a" (result),"Nd" (portnumber)
    );
    return result;
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Результат после первого двоеточия должен быть:

```
uint8_t Port8Bit::Read()
{
    uint8_t result;
    __asm__ volatile (
        "inb %1, %0"
        : "=a" (result)
        : "Nd" (portnumber)
    );
    return result;
}
```

Comment: И всё будет компилить

Comment: @Сергей Почитайте немного как правильно использовать ассемблерные вставки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829965/177722

Comment: там знак присваивания = постоянно в ошибке фигурирует что делать